# Is there a way to detect if Mb4/X1 is held down in Python?

Tags: python

Ive tried multiple libraries and cant find a good way to do this.

I tried keyboard library, but i could not find anywhere what the name for x1 would be. I do not want to use Pynput because of the fact it is pressed only, not hold.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I have found a way using win32api.

```
if win32api.GetKeyState(0x05)<0:
        left_click()
```